# Is it possible to detect at instantiation time all of a given type's callable methods and then dynamically create a forwarding process for each method

Tags: javascript, class, methods, dynamic

I needed a sort of aggregate class that forwards it's method calls to all of it's constituents. This is what I wrote:

```js
class CompositeSpritesheet {
    sprites = []; // collect Spritesheet objects
    draw() {
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s.draw.apply(s, arguments)))
    }
    init() {
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s.init.apply(s, arguments)))
    }
    nextStep() {
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s.nextStep.apply(s, arguments)))
    }
    // ... for all possible functions
}

let board = new Spritesheet("a");
let text = new Spritesheet("b");

let composite = new CompositeSpritesheet();
composite.sprites.push(wood,text);
composite.draw(20,30);
```

This code is really repetitive, not exhaustive, might fail for unexpected function calls, and most importantly just really icky. Is there a way I can generalize this and maybe write a higher-order class that generates such compositions at whim?

In other words, is there a mechanism in JavaScript that lets me replicate the following pseudocode's behavior?

```
class CompositeSpritesheet{
    sprites = [];
    *("fn", args){
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s[fn]?.apply(s, arguments)))
    }
}
```

This could be a dumb question, but I find JavaScript flexible in many unexpected ways that I haven't been able to completely wrap my head around. I feel like it could possible in some form or another.

If you have ideas that don't completely answer the question but are still related to the solution, feel free to post them as comments.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your after here but it sounds a lot like what RXJS does https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

Comment: Are possible methods detectable at instantiation/construction time of a `CompositeSpritesheet ` type? ... like one has an array with all the possible sprites, collects all the methods and then does dynamically create all necessary forwarding wrapper methods from within the constructor function.

Comment: Ben's approach/idea is the most valuable so far for it is clean and lean. I would implement this method as `execute (actionName, argsArray) { ... }`

Comment: @PeterSeliger They are detectable at construction time. Could you please expand on your idea?

Comment: @Nirav ... "Could you please expand on your idea?" ... certainly ... but one more question ... do all possibly listed sprites always feature the same set of methods?

Comment: @PeterSeliger absolutely.

Comment: ... and a sprite's methods are "known" at construction time by a) either passing the method names as list to the constructor or b) as soon as the first sprite becomes a member of the (internal) sprite list, such an item could reveal it's enumerable methods by e.g `Object.keys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... something like this ..?

```
class CompositeSpritesheet {
  constructor(...sprites) {
    let spriteList = [].concat(...sprites);

    this.addSprites = (...sprites) => {
      spriteList = spriteList.concat(...sprites);
    };
    this.execute = (actionName, ...args) => {
      spriteList.forEach(sprite => {

        const action = sprite[actionName];
        if (typeof action === 'function') {

          action.apply(sprite, args);
        }
      });
    };
  }
}

let board = new Spritesheet("a");
let text = new Spritesheet("b");

let composite = new CompositeSpritesheet();

composite.addSprites(board, text);
composite.execute('draw', 20, 30);
```

#### Edit / Second Iteration

The next provided approach is a generic one. Knowing that at any time every internally listed `Spritesheet` type does feature the same set of methods, a newly introduced `CompositeSpritesheet` type does now detect all accessible keys of its first listed `Spritesheet` element, either at construction time or as soon as such (an) element(s) will be concatenated to the composite type's internally managed spritesheet-list. Then, while iterating this key-list, for every found spritesheet-method a corresponding forwarder method gets created dynamically.

... working example code ...

```js
function isBooleanValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'boolean');
}
function isNumberValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'number');
}
function isStringValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'string');
}

function isSymbol(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'symbol');
}

function isPrimitive(type) {
  return (
    isBooleanValue(type)
    || isNumberValue(type)
    || isStringValue(type)
    || isSymbol(type)
  );
}
function isObject(type) {
  return (!!type && (typeof type === 'object'));
}
function isFunction(type) {
  const functionType = 'function';
  return (
    (typeof type === functionType)
    && (typeof type.call === functionType)
    && (typeof type.apply === functionType)
  );
}

/**
 *  - recursively collect a list of a type’s accessible keys
 *    that also might be inherited, but that are neither keys
 *    of `Object.prototype` nor keys of `Function.prototype`.
 */
function getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(type, keyList) {
  // default return value.
  keyList = (keyList || []);

  // accept primitive data types as well.
  if (isPrimitive(type)) {
    type = Object(type);
  }

  // undefined and null value are kept out.
  if (isObject(type)) {

    keyList = keyList.concat(
      Object.keys(type)
    ).concat(
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(type)
    );
    const protoType = (isFunction(type.constructor) && type.constructor.prototype);

    if (protoType && (protoType !== Object.prototype)) {
      if (protoType === protoType.constructor.prototype) {

        keyList = keyList.concat(
          Object.keys(protoType)
        ).concat(
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(protoType)
        );
      } else {
        keyList = getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(protoType, keyList);
      }
    }
    const proto = type.__proto__;

    if ((isObject(proto) || isFunction(proto)) && (proto !== Object.prototype)) {
      if (proto === proto.__proto__) {

        keyList = keyList.concat(
          Object.keys(proto)
        ).concat(
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)
        );
      } else {
        keyList = getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(proto, keyList);
      }
    }
  }
  return [...(new Set(keyList))].filter(key => !(/^\d+$/).test(key));
}

function isEmptyList(type) {
  return ((type = Object(type)) && ('length' in type) && (Array.from(type).length === 0));
}

function withSpritesheetForwarderMethods(sharedState) {
  // guard.
  if (sharedState.hasForwarderMethods || isEmptyList(sharedState.spritesheetList)) {
    // either does already feature all methods or there is still nothing to work with.
    return;
  }
  const compositeType = this;
  const spritesheetType = sharedState.spritesheetList[0];

  getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(spritesheetType).forEach((key) => {
    if (isFunction(spritesheetType[key])) {

      // apply spritesheet forwarder method.
      compositeType[key] = function (...args) {
        sharedState.spritesheetList.forEach(

          (spritesheet) => spritesheet[key].apply(spritesheet, args)
        );
      }
    }
  });
  sharedState.hasForwarderMethods = true;
}

function withSpritesheetListManagement(sharedState) {
  const compositeType = this;

  compositeType.addSpritesheets = (...spritesheets) => {

    sharedState.spritesheetList = sharedState.spritesheetList.concat(...spritesheets);

    // ... either applicable latest at concat time ...
    withSpritesheetForwarderMethods.call(compositeType, sharedState);
  };
  // ... or (preferably) already applicable at construction time.
  withSpritesheetForwarderMethods.call(compositeType, sharedState);
}

class CompositeSpritesheet {
  constructor(...spritesheets) {

    const compositeType = this;
    const sharedState = {
      hasForwarderMethods: false,
      spritesheetList: [].concat(...spritesheets)
    };
    withSpritesheetListManagement.call(compositeType, sharedState);
  }
}

class Spritesheet {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  draw(...args) {
    console.log(`"${ this.name }" :: draw :: args : `, args);
  }
}


// test 1 :: apply forwarder methods at construction time.

const board = new Spritesheet("board");
const text = new Spritesheet("text");

const forwardingAtConstructionTime = new CompositeSpritesheet([board, text]);

console.log('forwardingAtConstructionTime.draw : ', forwardingAtConstructionTime.draw);

forwardingAtConstructionTime.draw(20, 30);


// test 2 :: apply forwarder methods at concat time.

const wood = new Spritesheet("wood");
const paper = new Spritesheet("paper");

const forwardingAtConcatTime = new CompositeSpritesheet();

console.log('forwardingAtConcatTime.draw : ', forwardingAtConcatTime.draw);

forwardingAtConcatTime.addSpritesheets(wood, paper);
forwardingAtConcatTime.draw(50, 10);

console.log('forwardingAtConcatTime.draw : ', forwardingAtConcatTime.draw);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

#### Edit / Third Iteration

The design of the 3rd iteration is much cleaner. The class implementation is straight forward. The glue code work of dynamically creating the forwarding actions is done by a factory named `from` with this factory also being the only method of its `CompositeSpritesheet` namespace. Thus, this factory needs any randomly chosen or ad hoc created `Spritesheet` type in order to then create an according `CompositeSpritesheet` type.

... working example code ...

```js
function isBooleanValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'boolean');
}
function isNumberValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'number');
}
function isStringValue(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'string');
}

function isSymbol(type) {
  return (typeof type === 'symbol');
}

function isPrimitive(type) {
  return (
    isBooleanValue(type)
    || isNumberValue(type)
    || isStringValue(type)
    || isSymbol(type)
  );
}
function isObject(type) {
  return (!!type && (typeof type === 'object'));
}
function isFunction(type) {
  const functionType = 'function';
  return (
    (typeof type === functionType)
    && (typeof type.call === functionType)
    && (typeof type.apply === functionType)
  );
}

/**
 *  - recursively collect a list of a type’s accessible keys
 *    that also might be inherited, but that are neither keys
 *    of `Object.prototype` nor keys of `Function.prototype`.
 */
function getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(type, keyList) {
  // default return value.
  keyList = (keyList || []);

  // accept primitive data types as well.
  if (isPrimitive(type)) {
    type = Object(type);
  }

  // undefined and null value are kept out.
  if (isObject(type)) {

    keyList = keyList.concat(
      Object.keys(type)
    ).concat(
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(type)
    );
    const protoType = (isFunction(type.constructor) && type.constructor.prototype);

    if (protoType && (protoType !== Object.prototype)) {
      if (protoType === protoType.constructor.prototype) {

        keyList = keyList.concat(
          Object.keys(protoType)
        ).concat(
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(protoType)
        );
      } else {
        keyList = getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(protoType, keyList);
      }
    }
    const proto = type.__proto__;

    if ((isObject(proto) || isFunction(proto)) && (proto !== Object.prototype)) {
      if (proto === proto.__proto__) {

        keyList = keyList.concat(
          Object.keys(proto)
        ).concat(
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)
        );
      } else {
        keyList = getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(proto, keyList);
      }
    }
  }
  return [...(new Set(keyList))].filter(key => !(/^\d+$/).test(key));
}


const CompositeSpritesheet = (function () {
  // module scope.

  // lean class.
  class CompositeSpritesheet {
    // declare private instance field.
    #list

    constructor() {
      // initialize private instance field.
      this.#list = [];
    }

    // prototypal instance methods with private instance field access.
    getSpritesheets() {
       return [...this.#list];
    }
    addSpritesheets(...spritesheets) {
       return [...(this.#list = this.#list.concat(...spritesheets))];
    }
  }

  // creation helper.
  function createForwardingAction(composite, key) {
    composite[key] = function (...args) {
      composite.getSpritesheets().forEach(

        (spritesheet) => spritesheet[key].apply(spritesheet, args)
      );
    }
  }

  // factory.
  function createCompositeFromSpritesheetType(dummySpritesheet) {
    const composite = new CompositeSpritesheet();

    getAllAccessiblePropertyNames(dummySpritesheet).forEach((key) => {
      if (isFunction(dummySpritesheet[key])) {

        // apply spritesheet forwarder method.
        createForwardingAction(composite, key);
      }
    });
    return composite;
  }

  // module export.
  return {
    from: createCompositeFromSpritesheetType
  };

}());


class Spritesheet {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  draw(...args) {
    console.log(`"${ this.name }" :: draw :: args : `, args);
  }
}


// test
const composite = CompositeSpritesheet.from(new Spritesheet);

console.log('composite : ', composite);
console.log('get current spritesheet list : ', composite.getSpritesheets());

const board = new Spritesheet("board");
const text = new Spritesheet("text");
const wood = new Spritesheet("wood");
const paper = new Spritesheet("paper");

console.log('add [board, text] to list : ', composite.addSpritesheets(board, text));
composite.draw(20, 30);

composite.addSpritesheets([wood, paper]); // add via array is possible too.
console.log('get current spritesheet list : ', composite.getSpritesheets());

composite.draw(50, 10);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is certainly a clean solution for a new project. But I'd have to convert almost every function call my fairly large codebase to make this work.

Comment: @Nirav ... so it is mainly that you want to be able to continue using `let composite = new CompositeSpritesheet();
composite.sprites.push(wood,text);
composite.draw(20,30);`?

Comment: Just composite.draw(20,30). In general, I want to pass CompositeSpritesheet object to every class I could pass Spritesheet() without having to modify preexisting code that already uses it.

Comment: this is great! I'll take some time to understand and apply this idea, then set this as accepted answer.

Comment: Something is still not answered; does one "know" always at instantiation time all the method names (then the amount of the 3rd iteration's code could be reduced at least to half) or does such a method name list need to be created by introspection of a provided example type as shown with the last approach?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Given the comments in the other answer, what you could do is to create your class and then add the functions to the prototype:

```
class CompositeSpritesheet {
    sprites = [];
};

var functionsToCreate = ["draw", "init", "nextStep"];

for (let f of functionsToCreate) {
    CompositeSpritesheet.prototype[f] = function() {
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s[f].apply(s, arguments)));
    }
}
```

And so CompositeSpritesheet will have all the functions you want in its prototype and so you will be able to call `composite.draw(20,30);`.

The only thing you have to do is to fill the `functionsToCreate` array.

=====================

A solution I can see could be to call only one method with different arguments:

```
class CompositeSpritesheet {
    function doSomething(action, args) {
        this.sprites.forEach(s => (s[action].apply(s, args)));
}
```

So you can call `composite.doSomething("draw", [20,30]);`.

Comment: This is great. I think it's possible in JS to enumerate all methods of a class and dynamically repopulate `functionsToCreate` array. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yes it is: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourObject).filter(p => typeof yourObject[p] === 'function')`